# Meteor template data context not available in template.created upon refresh

Tags: javascript, meteor, page-refresh, iron-router

I use the template data context inside a template's `created` function.

```
Template.temp.created = function() { console.log('this.data'); };
```

When I go to the page normally--i.e. click the link to the page--I see the console log the correct data object. When I hit the refresh button on the page, `this.data` is `null`.

Why?

---

Also, I am using iron-router to set the data context:

```
...
this.route('temp', {
    ...
    data: function() { return MyCollection.findOne(someId); },
    ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to wait until data come then use `waitOn`.

```
this.route('temp', {
    waitOn:function(){
      return this.subscribe("nameOfPublishFunction");
    },
    data: function() { return MyCollection.findOne(someId); },
    ...
}
```

Remember to activate loading hook (thanks @Peppe L-G):

```
Router.onBeforeAction("loading");
```

[IronRouter docs #waitOn](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/DOCS.md#waiting-on-subscriptions-waiton)

#### Update

[Here](https://github.com/parhelium/laboratory/tree/master/meteor/data-availability-in-template-created) you can find sample meteor app with iron:router package which shows how turning loading hook on and off (    `Router.onBeforeAction("loading")`) changes availability of data to `created` and `rendered` methods.

Comment: Have they changed so the loading hook is included by default? Otherwise you need to add it too in order for it to work.

Comment: Hang in there @B-Brock, they're considering changing it to be included by default :) https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/819